# Error on accessing java web app

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I just started learning Java for Web Developers today. I am following a tutorial in the book chapter 2. I have checked it line by line and everything is the same. I do not know enough about it yet to figure out the problem. Here is my error:

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class apress.helloworld.HelloWorld
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: apress.helloworld.HelloWorld
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1324)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1177)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my code:

```
package apress.helloworld;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HellowWorld extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
            printWriter.println("<h2>");
            printWriter.println("hello World!");
            printWriter.println("</h2>");

        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and web.xml (not sure if its relevant or not)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>helloworld</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>apress.helloworld.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Can anyone help me with this so I can learn java??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have typo in the class name (additional 'w'). Fix, recompile and world will be beautiful again. Remember to change file name to match class name. ;)

```
public class HellowWorld extends HttpServlet
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. This simple things are so easy to overlook. But from that error code, how could you tell that was the problem?

Comment: @alexander7567 it's infinitely easier to spot somebody else's typos than the own. Whenever there's an unexplainable error (or just a situation that "should" work), the first thing is to look for typos. ClassNotFoundExceptions are classic examples for this.

Comment: @Gas Okay, i see that error now. Thank you very much! The problem is fixed and i can now learn the code! And ill know what to look our for next time i have an unexplainable problem!

Comment: You could see that because there was ClassNotFound Exception, so either there is something wrong with packaging or with the class itself. You could of course fix it the other way around - change the class name in the descriptor <servlet-class>apress.helloworld.HelloWorld</servlet-class>. But I assumed, you rather wanted your class to be named HelloWorld than HellowWorld :)

Answer (score 1):

In the error message you got, the bottom line of the first portion says "Unknown Source" and that may be because it cannot find your class.  This is because you have it under the package "apress.helloworld" but spelled your class name as "HellowWorld".  Fix the class name and everything should be up and running.